# How to enter and pass text coordinates (tkinter)?

Tags: python, tkinter

I need to write a program using tkinter to organize string input and data input about text placement in a window. I tried to write the code, how should I pass the coordinates?

```
from tkinter import *
win = Tk()
lab_tx=Label(win, bg="#F2EECB",width="60",height="30")
lab_x = Label(win, text=' x:')
lab_y = Label(win, text='y:')

tx=Entry(win)
x = Entry(win)
y = Entry(win)

but=Button(win,text="Start")

def rplace(event):
    lab_tx['text']=tx.get()

tx.grid(row=0,column=0)
x.grid(row=1,column=0)
y.grid(row=2,column=0)
lab_tx.grid(row=3,column=0)
lab_x.grid(row=4,column=0)
lab_y.grid(row=5,column=0)
but.grid(row=6,column=0)
but.bind("<Button-1>",rplace)
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: The coordinates are already being passed as part of the `event` object.

Comment: do want to place the text in a specific area in your window ?

Comment: @Ayyoub ESSADEQ
yes